# How do I write a function as both an event handler and a callable function that takes an argument?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

Here's a function for use as an event handler that makes use of `this`:

```
function validate() {
  if (this.val() == '') {
    return false;
  }
}

$(':input').change(validate);
```

Here's the same function rewritten to take an argument, so that I can call it explicitly:

```
function validate(field) {
  if ($(field).val() == '') {
    return false;
  }
}

validate($('#customer_name'));
```

How can I rewrite my `validate` function to make it suitable for use as *both* an event handler, and as a standalone function for me to call?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are various ways to do this. One is to use the second one taking the field as a parameter and set the event handler using a closure:

```
function validate(field) {
  if ($(field).val() == '') {
    return false;
  }
}

// Use anonymous function to pass "this" to validate.
$(':input').change(function() { validate(this); });

// Unchanged.
validate($('#customer_name'));
```

Another way is to use the first form and use [apply()](http://www.webreference.com/js/column26/apply.html) to call it with an overridden `this`:

```
function validate() {
  if ($(this).val() == '') {
    return false;
  }
}

// Unchanged.
$(':input').change(validate);

// Use `$(...)` as "this" when calling validate.
validate.apply($('#customer_name'));
```

Comment: +1 for apply(). It's the nicer, more idiomatic alternative, IMHO.

Comment: PS: There's an error in your second code sample. I think it should be `$(this)` in the function body.

Answer (score 5):

Use a fallback to `this` if `field` is not given as an argument.

```
function validate(field) {
    return $(field || this).val() != '';
}

$(':input').change(validate); // using this context
validate($('#someInput'));    // using a parameter
```